# How to setup Django every time you use it? (i.e. using **source bin/activate** and ** python manage.py runserver**)

Tags: python, django, django-errors

I am a beginner with Django, and I am very confused as to how to consistently setup Django everytime you are opening a new terminal. Whenever I do so, I have to always restart and do the following:

1. Change directory (`cd`) to my **trydjango** directory where I start the virtual environment (`source bin/activate`)
2. After the terminal has the automatic `(trydjango)` at the furthest left of `(trydjango) lyons-MacBook-Air:trydjango lyons$` I know that I have the virtual environment enabled.
3. Then, I go to the **src** directory through the terminal where I enter `python manage.py runserver`

I am running into consistent errors (e.g. AttributeError) whenever I enter the `runserver` step (step 3). Am I doing something wrong?

The following is the full **Traceback** of the error

```
(trydjango) lyons-MacBook-Air:src lyons$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10d5a6b90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 399, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 540, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/src/trydjango/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
NameError: name 'home_view' is not defined
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10d4a3b90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 399, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 540, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/lyons/Dev/trydjango/src/trydjango/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('', views.home_view, name='home'),
AttributeError: module 'pages.views' has no attribute 'home_view'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home_view(*args, **kwargs): # args, kwargs
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello World</h1>") # string of HTML code
```

**urls.py**

```
"""trydjango URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from pages import views #from pages import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_view, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Please include the full `Traceback` message that lead up to the `AttributeError`.

Comment: `AttributeError` is an exception which is probably raised from your codebase, that doesn't  do anything with your virtual environment

Comment: Just updated my description with the files and full traceback

Comment: hi..can you share your project file structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to tell you what exact steps to start a project.

1. `django-admin startproject new_project_name`
   Create a new project
2. `manage.py runserver IP:Port`
   Run server when start, http://127.0.0.1:8000/, or http://localhost:8000/
3. `manage.py startapp new_APP_name`
   in new_project_name to create a new APP
4. `manage.py makemigrations`
   in new_project_name to tell django project changed, then build a migration file.
5. `manage.py migrate`
   in new_project_name to update.
6. in new_project_name/new_project_name/settings.py
   `INSTALLED_APPS` add item with `new_APP_name.apps.new Appconfig subclass name` in new_APP_name\apps.py
7. in new_project_name/new_project_name/urls.py add you URL parser, for example

   ```py
   from . import views

   urlpatterns = [
       path('', views.Topic, name='index')
   ]
   ```
8. in new_project_name/new_APP_name/admin.py register model for example,

   ```py
   from .models import Topic

   admin.site.register(Topic)
   ```